# What is the lowest computational complexity of multiplying two non-square matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-complexity

Based on [Wikipedia information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations), the computational complexity of multiplying two $n\times n$ matrices can be $\mathcal{O}(n^{2.37})$ using algorithms similar to Coppersmith–Winograd.

I wonder what if we want to multiply a $n\times m$ matrix by a $m\times p$ matrix? Is there any algorithm providing a more efficient complexity than $\mathcal{O}(nmp)$?

Comment: If $n$ and $p$ were multiples of $m$ then you could do the square-matrix multiplications individually. But the more general case will need more delicate reasoning. Might this be a better fit in Computer Science Stack Exchange?

Comment: Are the matrices structured?